# How to set justMyCode False while debugging using docker in VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a code in VSCode that runs inside of docker. After realizing the problem is not in my code but in a Library that I am using I tried to set `justMyCode : false` in the `launch.json` file.

The problem is that when one is debugging inside of docker the lauch.json don't accept `justMyCode : false` and even when I put it there it does not work.

My config files:

lauch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - General",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "justMyCode": false, #This does not work
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "general"

            }

        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build",
            "platform": "python",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "tag": "indeednewversionnoapi:latest",
                "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "pull": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "dependsOn": [
                "docker-build"
            ],
            "python": {
                "file": "main.py",
                "args": ["--location","new_york", "--country","us","--from_age","14"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the placement of `justMyCode` field.

When you are running without docker you can use justMyCode directly in the configurations:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Arquivo Atual",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "args": [ "--location","New York", "--country","us","--from_age","14"]

        }
    ]
}
```

But while using docker it must go inside of python configs:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - General",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "general",
                "justMyCode": false,
            }
            
        }
    ]
}
```